# vagrant-berkshelf no longer works after upgrade to vagrant 1.4

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, berkshelf

I upgraded to the latest version of vagrant

```
$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.4.1
```

Re-installed my plugins:

```
# Uninstall plugins
for i in vagrant-omnibus vagrant-chef-zero vagrant-berkshelf
do vagrant plugin uninstall $i
done

# Install plugins
for i in vagrant-omnibus vagrant-chef-zero vagrant-berkshelf
do vagrant plugin install $i
done

$ vagrant plugin list
vagrant-berkshelf (1.3.7)
vagrant-chef-zero (0.5.2)
vagrant-omnibus (1.2.1)
```

But the vagrant-berkshelf plugin doesn't load.

```
$ vagrant up
Failed to load the "vagrant-berkshelf" plugin. View logs for more details.
```

Stacetrace

```
DEBUG environment: Loading plugins from: /home/mark/.vagrant.d/plugins.json
 INFO environment: Loading plugin from JSON: vagrant-omnibus
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: vagrant-omnibus
 INFO environment: Loading plugin from JSON: vagrant-chef-zero
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: chef_zero
 INFO environment: Loading plugin from JSON: vagrant-berkshelf
ERROR root: Failed to load plugin: vagrant-berkshelf
ERROR root:  -- Error: #<Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate berkshelf-2.0.10, because ridley-2.4.0 conflicts with ridley (~> 1.5.0)>
ERROR root:  -- Backtrace:
ERROR root: /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2007:in `raise_if_conflicts'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1176:in `activate'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1212:in `block in activate_dependencies'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1198:in `each'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1198:in `activate_dependencies'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1180:in `activate'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:186:in `rescue in try_activate'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:183:in `try_activate'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:117:in `rescue in require'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:124:in `require'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant.rb:200:in `require_plugin'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:760:in `block in load_plugins'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:751:in `each'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:751:in `load_plugins'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:132:in `initialize'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/bin/vagrant:105:in `new'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/bin/vagrant:105:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `load'
/opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `<main>'
 INFO interface: error: Failed to load the "vagrant-berkshelf" plugin. View logs for more details.

Failed to load the "vagrant-berkshelf" plugin. View logs for more details.
```

Does anyone know how to trouble-shoot gem conflicts between vagrant plugins?

```
ERROR root:  -- Error: #<Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate berkshelf-2.0.10, 
   because ridley-2.4.0 conflicts with ridley (~> 1.5.0)>
```

Comment: similarly, did you run into this type of problem with Vagrant 1.4.1 at all - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116710/upgrade-from-vagrant-1-3-5-to-1-4-3-problems-on-vagrant-up? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also uninstall Ridley 2.4 via

```
env GEM_HOME=~/.vagrant.d/gems gem uninstall ridley -v 2.4.0
```

Comment: +1 Thx very much. Much better work-around. Using Berkshelf 3.0 was causing me unrelated problems. I also now better understand how vagrant manages its gems, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. Until we have time to release a new version, you can use the "bleeding edge" as described here: https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf/wiki/Howto:-Use-the-bleeding-edge.

Sources:

- Core team member

Comment: +1 The deprecation warning berkshelf 3.0 throws inspired me to dig some more details on the new functionality. Found this: http://prezi.com/knlq4ojxbk_c/berkshelf-30/  Keep up the good work, Berkshelf is a great tool!