# Upgrade from Vagrant 1.3.5 to 1.4.3. Fails on `vagrant-berkshelf` plugin

Tags: vagrant, berkshelf

Note - this question is also posted in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/aZOs1YXmvhI

**Setup**

```
C:\Users\Kevin>vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.4.3

C:\Users\Kevin>VBoxManage -version # VirtualBox version
4.3.10r93012

C:\Users\Kevin>vagrant plugin list
vagrant-berkshelf (2.0.0)
vagrant-omnibus (1.3.1)
vagrant-vbguest (0.10.0)

C:\Users\Kevin>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
```

**EDIT** I just installed & updated my %PATH% to use ruby 2.0, but still having the same issue.

On a `Windows 7` PC, I was using `Vagrant 1.3.5` with `VirtualBox 4.3.8`, but upgraded to the above versions in order to attempt to fix a shared directory problem - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/eC72_YXdtYE.

Anyway, after upgrading to the first listed versions, I destroyed my VM with VirtualBox using "Remove / Delete All Files." Then I tried, unsuccessfully, to spin up a VM with `vagrant up`:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
C:/Users/Kevin/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-2.0.0/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/env.rb:16:in `initialize': undefined method `opts' for #<Vagrant::
UI::Colored:0x565e7c8> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Users/Kevin/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-2.0.0/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/action.rb:57:in `new'
        from C:/Users/Kevin/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-2.0.0/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/action.rb:57:in `block in setup'
        from C:/Users/Kevin/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-2.0.0/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/action.rb:56:in `tap'
        from C:/Users/Kevin/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-2.0.0/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/action.rb:56:in `setup'
        from C:/Users/Kevin/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-2.0.0/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/plugin.rb:15:in `provision'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant_1.4.3/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:45:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant_1.4.3/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant_1.4.3/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:44:in `tap'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant_1.4.3/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:44:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant_1.4.3/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:43:in `map'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant_1.4.3/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:43:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant_1.4.3/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:147:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant_1.4.3/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.3/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

How can I debug this error?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is has already been reported, answered, and closed on the [vagrant-berkshelf issue tracker](https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/issues/181).

Comment: I'd close this, but is it useful for folks to view this post, and then see your answer, @Seth?

Answer (score 4):

You can install a version of Vagrant-Berkshelf that works with Vagrant 1.4.3

`vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-berkshelf
vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf --plugin-version 1.3.7`